# After making successful payment with flutterwave-react-native, i get this error

Tags: react-native, flutterwave

After making successful payment with flutterwave-react-native, i get this error. Can't open url: file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B7772AE9-4650-4076-8389-8E2A243D5DFE/Expo%20Go.app/

```
const handleRedirect = (data) => {
    if (data.status === "successful") {
      handlePaymentOnTheServer(data.transaction_id);
    }
  };
<PayWithFlutterwave
                    onRedirect={handleRedirect}
                    options={{
                      tx_ref: new Date().toString(),
                      authorization:
                        "FLWPUBK_TEST-9337393620292-92622827-X",
                      customer: {
                        email: user.email,
                      },
                      amount: Number(amount),
                      currency: "NGN",
                      payment_options: "card",
                      customizations: {
                        title: "Recharge your Account",
                        description:
                          "While recharging your account, note 1.7% processing fee.",
                      },
                    }}
                    customButton={(props) => (
                      <AppButton
                        title='Submit'
                        style={{
                          paddingHorizontal: 40,
                        }}
                        onPress={() => {
                          if (amount) {
                            props.onPress();
                          } else {
                            showToast("Enter amount!");
                          }
                        }}
                        disabled={processing}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try install patched version

```
npm i git+https://github.com/Flutterwave/flutterwave-react-native/#fix-redirect-error
```

https://github.com/Flutterwave/flutterwave-react-native/issues/15#issuecomment-765316621